# Download Data Using HTTPClient

Tags: java, httpclient

Had a question about using Apache HTTPClient. I need to pull data from a website and found this useful tutorial https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html

In the tutorial it says we will write a simple application that "downloads a page".

Where exactly does it "download" the page to? I am not seeing mention of a database being set up so or some cloud storage or whatnot so where does the information "go" exactly (or where is it being held once the data is pulled)? I'm somewhat new to Java so this is a bit conceptual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "download" goes to `System.out`:

```
  // Read the response body.
  byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();

  // Deal with the response.
  // Use caution: ensure correct character encoding and is not binary data
  System.out.println(new String(responseBody));
```

Comment: Awesome...thanks very much. I never thought of that before and always just used system.out.println without thinking about it. That actually solidified my understanding in terms of OOP and and engineering quite a bit.